# Android Getting Results from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a problem with my code. I want to pass a String from the **SecondActivity** to **FirstActvity**. Note that the **FirstActivity** is not visible but its still open. when the **SecondActivity** is finish it passes a String to the **FirstActivity**.

My problem here is that when the **SecondActivity** ended and goes to **FirstActivity**, the whole application closes.

FirstActivity to SecondActivity:

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileChooser.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

SecondActivity to FirstActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("filePath", "/sdcard/path1");
setResult(0);
finish();
```

FirstActivity Result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //TODO handle here.         
    Intent intent = getIntent();        
    this.filePath = intent.getExtras().getString("filePath");
}
```

**What is wrong with the code?**

Comment: You've given everything except what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the result of your SecondActivity, you only set the result code. Instead of [`setResult(0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) use [`setResult(0,intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Also, in your FirstActivity's onActivityResult get the extra from the `data` argument - `this.filePath = data.getExtras().getString("filePath");`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
data.getExtras().getString("filePath");
```

instead of

```
intent.getExtras().getString("filePath");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Bundle:

**First Activity;**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FIRSTACTIVITY.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("filePath","/sdcard/path1");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);               
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Second Activity:**

```
public void activity_value() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras=i.getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {           
        value = extras.getString("filePath");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=C7CD6C9C9CFBD490DCE7EA024F774381?recipeId=899)
example.It solves your problem.